# d.js v14 - get all non bots & non offline members

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I just simply wanted to do stats of non bot users, non bot online users, and bot users

Non bot users and bot users work perfectly fine, but non bot online users return to me random numbers

```
        await guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true }).then(async fetchedMembers => {
            const onlineS = await fetchedMembers.filter(member => !member.presence || member.presence?.status !== 'offline' && !member.user.bot);
            console.log(onlineS.size)
        })
```

currently im using this to get non bot online users count, but it just returns random numbers and always member.presence is null, that's how i initialize my client

```
const client = new Client({ 
    intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMembers, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.GuildVoiceStates, GatewayIntentBits.GuildPresences ],
    partials: [Partials.Message, Partials.Channel, Partials.Reaction, Partials.GuildMember],
    allowedMentions: { parse: [ 'roles', 'users' ] }
});
```

so everything should work just fine, is there some sort of mistake i made?

ps. i have presence intent enabled in discord developer portal

Answer (score 0):

what helped me is to look if a user has a presence (online, dnd, idle) instead of looking if his presence is undefined. I'm not sure why the latter doesn't work correctly.

So in your code it would look like this:

```
await guild.members.fetch({ withPresences: true }).then(async fetchedMembers => {
    const onlineS = await fetchedMembers.filter(member => (member.presence?.status === 'online' || member.presence?.status === 'dnd' || member.presence?.status === 'idle') && !member.user.bot);
    console.log(onlineS.size)
});
```